# WSL Ubuntu: halt execution of a function on error

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a `bash` function that looks like this:

```
function myfunc()
{
    function __logErrAndExit()
    {
        echo "Error: $1"
        #exit 1  # Problematic spot
        return 1 # Problematic spot
    }

    commandA
    err=$?
    if [ "$err" -ne 0 ]; then
        __logErrAndExit "commandA failed"
    fi
    
    commandB
    err=$?
    if [ "$err" -ne 0 ]; then
        __logErrAndExit "commandB failed"
    fi
}
```

In the above code in `__logErrAndExit` function I have marked some lines as *# Problematic spot*. The current behaviour on execution is as follows:

If `__logErrAndExit` is set to `return 1` and there is an error on `commandA`, the function proceeds to `commandB`. Execution does not halt.

If `__logErrAndExit` is set to `exit 1` and there is an error on `commandA`, the WSL Ubuntu window just closes. I have to reopen the WSL Ubuntu window.

How can I achieve execution halt of `myfunc` without the window closure? Thank you.

Comment: Please define what you mean by _halting_ an execution. `return` terminates the function and execution continues at the calling side in the current process. `exit` terminates the process (and hence the function, which is part of the process) and continues with the calling side of the parent process. The behaviour is exactly like `return` and `exit` in C-programming.

Comment: @user1934428 After reading your definitions, I guess what I need is `exit` without the window closure.